# route resolving corrupted

Tags: 8

I have a weird situation. Somehow some routes got corrupted and I cannot fix them.

So the `/user/:uid/edit` and `/user/register` are corrupted, the `/user/:uid` , `/user/:uid/anything-else` , `/user/login` or `/user/password` works just fine.

After looking for database queries I found out that at some point drupal is looking for node entity instead of user entity and since no node with that ID is found it will throw 404 error (but the user in the breadcrumb is the correct one). I will attach some screenshots of this.

Any idea on how to fix this? Using devel to rebuild the menu did not fix the issue. Clearing the cache did not fix the issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are contributed modules installed?

Comment: some. It works ok on localhost, got corrupted on dev server

Comment: If this is a dev site you could run xdebug with stopping at exceptions and then see where it throws the 404.